# Simple Angular template text

Tags: angularjs

I'm pulling in a code block via ng-include, and in that code block I'd like to have an expression like

```
<h1>{{headingText}}</h1>
<p>{{paragraphText}}</p>
```

And on the destination page, I'd like to change that text at will, like so:

```
<script>
var headingText = "This is the heading";
var paragraphText = "This is some content text";
</script>
```

I can get expressions like {{2+2}} outputting as "4", but I can't get these variables to update with the text/string I supply. This seems to be easy, is it more difficult than this?

Comment: you need to set your variables in a $scope, therefore you need a controller to set the angularjs context

Answer (score 0):

It should be changed in some scope like that:

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <h1>{{headingText}}</h1>
    <p>{{paragraphText}}</p>
</div>

<script>
    function TestCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.headingText = "This is the heading";
        $scope.paragraphText = "This is some content text";
    }
</script>
```